# I am having issue seeing jekyll in browser. Nothing appears when I type 'localhost:4000' into url

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am new to this so hopefully I make sense when I ask this question.

I am doing this on windows 7 through the command prompt.

I have installed jekyll but I am having trouble with seeing the jekyll web page.  Nothing appears. What I see when I write 'jekkyl serve' is:

```
c:\users\spiridon\desktop\portfolio\jekyll serve
Configuration file: c:users/spiridon/desktop/portfolio/_config.yml
source:  c:users/spiridon/desktop/portfolio
destination: : c:users/spiridon/desktop/portfolio/_site
generating...
c:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.9/lib/posix/spawn.rb:164: warning: cannot close fd before spawn
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
←[31m Liquid Exception: no such file or directory - python c:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments/mentos.py in _posts/2014-10-23-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown←[0m
done.
Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
require 'rbconfig'
if RBConfig: :CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/i
gem 'wdm', >= 0.1.0'
end
Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'c:/users/spiridon/desktop/portfolio'
Configuration file: c:/users/spiridon/desktop/portfolio/_config.yml
server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

i am using ruby193
jekyll 2.4.0

this is my _config.yml:

```
# Site settings
title: Your awesome title
email: your-email@domain.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "http://yourdomain.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
twitter_username: jekyllrb
github_username:  jekyll

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
```

I am brand new to this language and most other programming languages.  I have also watched youtube videos and searched online for a solution but could not find anything. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Jekyll homepage

> While Windows is not an officially-supported platform, it can be used
>   to run Jekyll with the proper tweaks.

Please follow all instructions on [this page dedicated to hints to get Jekyll running on Windows](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/) or try this [Jekyll Windows project](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll).

The errors you get will probably be gone once you followed one of the above hints but still a short explanation:

> `'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

i.e. windows has no program called which.
which does not exists on Windows systems. On unixoid systems it's used to resolve what exactly is executed when you run the command given as attribute to which.

From the Wikipedia:

> In the Internet Protocol version 4 the address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target.

So it's no surprise opening it in the browser doesn't work. Jekyll cannot start a server at it runs into errors. So it displays this generic IP as server address.